# How to send an list to API using retrofit2

Tags: android, python, api, retrofit, eve

I developed an API using `EVE`.

This is the schema:

```
central_schema = {
    'name': {
        'type': 'string',
        'required': True,
    },
    'id_account': {
        'type': 'list',
    }
}
```

I'm trying to send a list using `retrofit 2`. I tried the API using `POSTMAN`. Everytime I got this response:

```
id account "must be of list type"
```

I used many types of requests (`PATCH`, `POST`, `PUT`), but I still get the same error.

Comment: I do not know retorfit2, but can you post the format of your request? The list format must be like "id_account" : ["1", "2"].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create Model class like below:

```
public class Model{
    public String name;
    public List<String> id_account;
}
```

And use it in retrofit 2.

It will produce below json:

```
{
    "name": "xyz",
    "id_account" : [
         "1",
         "2"
    ]
}
```